# Detecting Chrome plug-in warning

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, warnings

Is there any way to detect when Chrome shows the yellow bar at the top, asking the user to allow Java/Flash/Quicktime/whatever to run?

I'm developing a Javascript app that includes a small Java applet, and I want to be able to prompt the user to click the "Always Allow" button.

Right now I'm using a timeout to prompt the user if the applet isn't running within X seconds, but that's really hacky and unreliable solution.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe Chrome exposes this information. Doesn't Chrome display the default HTML fallback for <applet> etc. which could contain the information note until Allow is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The applet tag doesn't expose any events - what you could do is dynamically add the applet tag to your page using jQuery after you've shown the user a dialog to "Always Allow" (e.g. based on a cookie).